# Is it possible to stop windows from sending SOF packet to my USB device?

Tags: windows, usb

I want to test if my USB device will enter suspend after 3ms of IDLE state, but my PC host keeps send SOF packet every 1ms so I want to stop it for ~3ms. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to just tell your computer to go to sleep.

Another way that I think would work would be to connect your device to a USB hub (possibly a root hub inside your computer) that is not being used for any other devices, and then use the Device Manager to disable that hub.  Just right-click on the hub and select "Disable".